# check array is empty doesn't work using cast?

Tags: php

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM task where uId = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('s',$userId);

if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         $task[] = $obj;
    }

    if(count((array)$task)){
        $main[0]->tasks = $task;
    }
}
```

line `$main[0]->tasks = $task;` shows an error of `Undefined variable: task`. In my case there is no task in my record so the execution failed. But I expect it just skip and continue because I already put it within the 'if', which check whether the task object is empty.

Comment: *why* you are using cast at all?

Comment: how many rows this query supposed to return? if only one - why loops and arrays at all?

Comment: It's already an array. You just need to define it before your while loop. `$task = array();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    $task = array();
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         $task[] = $obj;
    }

    if(count($task)){ //or if($task){
        $main[0]->tasks = $task;
    }
}
```

Comment: so I forgot to init the $task array?